# Statusbar get enabled when presenting the photo album in IOS 7`

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios7

In my app I don't show the status bar.
In IOS 7 I had to add "View controller-based status bar appearance" to the info plist, which is fine, but when I use the following code:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = (sender == self.chooseImageBtn && [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) ?    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The status bar is shown again, even though I add the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fought with this for a long time as well. This is what finally got rid of it for me.

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *) navigationController   willShowViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = navigationController.topViewController.view.frame.size;
    }
}
```

Also, in your Info.plist, add:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance: NO
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had to put the following code in the if statement : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone]; instead of yours, but it worked like a charm. THANKS man

Comment: I just found a hidden bug that this triggers... If you hide the status bar while using the imagepicker, the imagepicker does not scroll to the bottom of the images (newest), but instead leaves the user at the top (oldest). Argh. Nice, Apple. Does this statusbar stuff really need to be this complicated?

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes when you open the imagepicker because the status bar is shown forcfully there.

I faced the same problem.

Here is my solution. put this in the viewWillAppear of the view controller from which you are opening the image pickerview

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work on IOS7. I have mentioned it in the question

Comment: Its working on my xcode and yes its 7.0
It appeared in the same senario in my code. i am wondering why its not working in your.

Comment: I don't know. I can check again

Comment: That works for me on iOS7!!! And I tried so many other solutions that didn't work. Thanks!